# Local notification in android from database

Tags: android, notifications, click, local

my requirement is to generate local notification when current time matches with the values in the database.But now the problem is that when I am clicking on the notification it should take me to the specific product details using the product id.

I have generated the notification but how can I get the product title/id to the product details page.

Code----------------

```
for (int i=0;i < alertList.size();i++) {
                Random random = new Random();
                int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
                msg=alertList.get(i).getProf_name()+" have to take "+alertList.get(i).getMed_name()+"                                                                                          ;"+alertList.get(i).getMed_id();
                Log.d("MediMSg",""+msg);
                Log.d("MediMSg",""+msg);
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MedicineNotificationActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("pushmsg",msg);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(MedicineNotificationActivity.class);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(100, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
                Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Test")
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setTicker("Notification from Test")
                        .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setColor(0x0091ea)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(m,notification);
                Log.d("Random",""+m);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate the notification, but the product title/id in the intent as extras. Then in your activity which is started byclicking the notification. You can access these extras.

You can create an array outside the loop, if you have multiple ids, like this:

```
int[] ids = new int[alertList.size()];
```

Then in the loop, iterate and set the id for each one on their respective indices.

```
for (int i=0;i < alertList.size();i++) {
     ids[i] = YOUR_ID;
     //OTHER Code
}
```

Lastly, put extra like this:

```
notificationIntent.putExtra("ids", ids);
```

Comment: I have just posted my code..How can i get the id on clicking the notification

Comment: Add the id to the intent like this: `notificationIntent.putExtra("id", YOUR_ID);`

Comment: Yes I have done that but it is returning the same id the last one.As it is inside the for loop.